# npm message saying warn, bad enginel

Tags: npm, nvm

I am trying to install react but I am unable to go any further since I keep getting and error of bad engine. It says my version is not compatible? It also says I hava versions 8.5.1 and V12.22.9? How can I solve this?

[image]

I tried running the upgrade and update command, also install Node version manager NVM and it says I have V20.4.0 but then gives me the bad engine error